# Checkstyle different severity for same module based on property

Tags: java, checkstyle

Is it possible to have different severity levels for the same module but with different properties?

This is what I am looking at:

```xml
<module name="IllegalThrows">
   <property name="illegalClassNames" value="NullPointerException,java.lang.RuntimeException,Exception"/>
</module>

<module name="IllegalThrows">
  <property name="illegalClassNames" value="Exception"/>
  <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's perfectly ok! There are some minor glitches in your example code; here's a slightly modified version:

```xml
<module name="IllegalThrows">
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    <property name="illegalClassNames"
        value="java.lang.NullPointerException,java.lang.RuntimeException"/>
</module>

<module name="IllegalThrows">
    <property name="severity" value="error"/>
    <property name="illegalClassNames" value="java.lang.Exception"/>
</module>
```

I set a `severity` on both modules. One can be left out if it is the same as the configured default severity (usually `warning`). Also, I removed the redundancy where `Exception` was declared in both modules. This would have caused you to get two issues for the same line of code. It is sufficient to specify only the fully qualified class names.